# scrollTo after focus/onClick event works only after second click

Tags: android, onclick, smooth-scrolling, onfocus

I try to scroll to specific point when the user click on edittext, so added the following code to listen to click and focus on this edittext:

```
    et_email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    //bring to center of screen when clicked / focused
    et_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewSendDetails);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);
        }
    });
    et_email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewSendDetails);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the scrolling works only after the second click. 
In the first click on the edittext nothing happens

Comment: I don't think you need the `OnFocusChangeListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but whoever is interested in a solution:
replacing

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500)
```

with

```
scrollView.postDelayed(() -> scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500), 200);
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to listener for the same? Try to use an onTouch listener:

```
et_email.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewSendDetails);
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```