# android EditText with TouchListener get focused only on second click

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I have added a setOnTouchListener to EditText in order to scroll the screen when the user click on it.
It works, but in the first click it scroll and only in the second click the EditText get focused and open the soft keyboard.
**How can I make the EditText get focused in the first click and not only in the second?**

```
et_email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

et_email.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewSendDetails);
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, et_email.getBottom() + 200);
        return false;
    }
});
```

btw I tried to add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused), but it doesn't help

Comment: try et_email .setFocusable(true);

Comment: yes IntelliJ Amiya I am using fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android auto scroll when clicked on edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298356/android-auto-scroll-when-clicked-on-edittext)

Comment: Please stop duplicating your own questions!

Answer (score 0):

**Use predefined method**

```
   et_email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

    et_email.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewSendDetails);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, et_email.getBottom() + 200);
            // method you can use to focus on edittext
            et_email.requestFocus();

            return false;
        }
    });
```