# Scroll content to bottom of page when EditText box is clicked

Tags: android

I am trying to have the app scrolled all the way to the bottom so that when the user clicks the username EditText box and/or password, he/she will be able to see the Log In button.

[Here's what I mean by using an example from the Facebook App.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlyE.png)

[And this is what my App is doing. Not what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCRW2.png)

Obviously, I did some research before submitting a question.

I've tried using setSoftInputMode to SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN and along with other ADJUST options. I also tried to do it the xml but still no luck.

I also tried using scrollView.scrollTo method, and set to button.getBottom() so it will scroll to the end of the button. But again, it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea of what I could be doing right?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android auto scroll when clicked on edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298356/android-auto-scroll-when-clicked-on-edittext)